# Output of array by rows

Tags: php, arrays

there is an array:

```
Array
(
    [33] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 2
            [4] => 1
            [5] => 1
            [6] => 2
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 5
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

)
```

What is the better way to print output this array as follows in php?:

```
raw1:33(1);22(1);11(1);
raw2:33(1);22(5);11();
raw3:33(5);22(5);11();
raw4:33(2);22();11();
raw5:33(1);22();11();
raw6:33(1);22();11();
raw7:33(2);22();11();
```

Comment: The better way than which way?

Comment: I think some clarification is needed!

Comment: I thought about using array_pop or just simply foreach. To fint array with most ampount of values and using for+foreach+array_pop to make output as above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is

```
$data = array(
  33 => array(
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 5,
    3 => 2,
    4 => 1,
    5 => 1,
    6 => 2,
  ),
  22 => array(
    0 => 1,
    1 => 5,
    2 => 5,
  ),
  11 => array(
    0 => 1,
  ),
);

$x = 1;
foreach ( new ColumnIterator($data) as $set ) {
    echo "raw$x:";
    foreach ( $set as $k => $v )
        echo $k . "($v);";
    echo "\n";
    $x ++;
}
```

Output

```
raw1:33(1);22(1);11(1);
raw2:33(1);22(5);11();
raw3:33(5);22(5);11();
raw4:33(2);22();11();
raw5:33(1);22();11();
raw6:33(1);22();11();
raw7:33(2);22();11();
```

[Online Demo](http://eval.in/6402)

Class Used

```
class ColumnIterator extends MultipleIterator {
    function __construct(array $multi) {
        parent::__construct(self::MIT_NEED_ANY | self::MIT_KEYS_ASSOC);
        foreach ( $multi as $k => $v ) {
            $this->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($v), $k);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thx, but in your example i should know values 33,22,11. But they are dynamical and i do not know them in advance.

Comment: many thx,I tried your previos code without clas and it works just fine. Why it is better to use Class?

Comment: and if campare perfomance is there any difference what is better?

Comment: All this are Micro Benchmark it does not matter .... but Iterators are naturally slower but more memory efficient .. depending on implementation

Comment: Ok, thx again, i will try to use your first code implementation without class.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this-

```
for($loop=0;$loop<count($array[33]);$loop++) {
    $arr1 = ($arr[33][$loop]) ? $arr[33][$loop] : "";
    $arr2 = ($arr[22][$loop]) ? $arr[22][$loop] : "";
    $arr3 = ($arr[11][$loop]) ? $arr[11][$loop] : "";
    echo "row".$loop+1.":33(".$arr1.");22(".$arr2.");11(".$arr3.")";
}
```

Comment: @Suresh Kamrushi, your idea is intersting but i have dynmic array not possible to use fixed values like in your example.